# Using "this" inside an object initializer

Tags: c#, initialization

I have the following issue:

```
public class ChildClass{
   public Object Parent = null;
}
public class ParentClass{
   public ChildClass CreateChild(){
        return new ChildClass{ Parent = this; }
   }
}
```

I got a bit stuck understanding object initializers. In the `CreateChild()` method, does `this` refer to `ParentClass` or `ChildClass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` will refer the the class it is in.

In the example, `this` will be an instance of `ParentClass`, since it is declared *within* the body of `ParentClass`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but isn't `this` belong to `ChildClass` in this case as it is inside its inializer?

Comment: @GETah - No it doesn't. The object initializer is still _within_ the `ParentClass` body.

Comment: @GETah, the initializer is shorthand to make your life somewhat easier and it isn't occuring inside the object being created. But step through the code, then you'll know.

Comment: @GETah - The context of `this` doesn't change within the object initializer.

Comment: No. How would you be able to pass the current instance of `ParentClass` to the new `ChildClass` object if it behaved like that. Only inside the `ChildClass` `this` refers to `ChildClass`. `var c = new ChildClass{ Parent = this };` is the same as `var c = new ChildClass();    c.Parent = this;`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Huuh got confused here. Do you mean that `this` refers to `ChildClass`?

Comment: The object initializer is NOT within `ChildClass` but within `ParentClass`. Therfore `this` refers to the current instance of `ParentClass`. The object initializer does NOT belong to `ChildClass` but is a code which belongs to the method `CreateChild` of `ParentClass`. Everything which is between "public class ParentClass{" and the final "}" belongs to `ParentClass`.

Answer (score 1):

It refers always to the class where it is textually imbedded. In this case to `ParentClass`.

---

**UPDATE**

The object initializer is NOT within `ChildClass` but within `ParentClass`. Therfore `this` refers to the current instance of `ParentClass`. The object initializer does NOT belong to `ChildClass` but is a code which belongs to the method `CreateChild` of `ParentClass`. Everything which is between "public class ParentClass{" and the final "}" belongs to `ParentClass`.

Answer (score 1):

To the instance of the ParentClass on which the CreateChild is executed (Though in its current way your code probably wont compile).
this = the instance of the current class, which in this case is the parentclass

Comment: It does compile, the `Parent` member variable can be anything that is why it is of type `Object`